# What part of Django actually calls the views in views.py?

Tags: python, django, view

I'm curious to learn more about the inner workings of Django.

One thing that I want to start with is following the chain of calls backwards from the functions in my `views.py` files.

For example, I have a function

```
def user_page(request):
     ...
```

which gets called with the url

```
...
url(r'^user/$', views.user_page, name='user_page'),
```

Where is the Django code that actually reads the URL, matches the pattern and calls my `view` function?

Answer (score 1):

First you have the webserver / python gateway specific details (`wsgi` or `fcgi` script etc). One way or another, this gateway specific part end up instanciating some `django.core.handlers.base.BaseHandler` subclass - very probably a `django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler` which is actually the only builtin `BaseHandler` subclass in 1.5.x (FWIW both the builtin dev server and the runfcgi command now end up using `wsgi`).

Assuming you're in this configuration (using `WSGIHandler` one way or another), the real "django" entry point is `WSGIHandler.__call__(environ, start_response)`, which in turn calls on `self.get_response(request)`, which is actually inherited from `BaseHandler`, and this is where most of the dispatching (middlewares, url resolution, view call etc) happens.

Answer (score -3):

Django Actually Calls the settings part to check the url pattern. then from this pattern, again it is searched for the corresponding view function for the url.